# printing a table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i have a dynamic angularjs table which i want to print on a buton click

this is my button

```
<button onclick="PrintUGridData()">print</button>
```

and this is my javascript

```
<script>
    function PrintUGridData() {
        var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('tuit');
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }
</script>
```

but the problem is i want to print the table using angularjs bcoz my hidden row's of the table is being printed in javascript

for example this is my hidden column which is being printed(`<td ng-hide="true">{{d.taskmid}}</td>`)

what i need to do if i want to print the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could access and bind to scope.

First access the scope

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('tuit')).scope();
```

Doing this you would get the scope of the element which it is binded. Now to bind the value, just bind the new value to scope variable. And just call apply method to update the view.

```
scope.$apply(function(){
  //whatever you want to assign in scope variable
  scope.true = false;
})
```

Comment: what i need to assign if i want to print the table